# finding out the way to show $333667$ is a prime number

Tags: prime-factorization

While doing prime factorization $12345679$

$x=12345679$

$10x=123456790$

$9x=111111111=111×1001001$

$x=37×333667$

we know $37$ is a prime, should I need to find out $333667$ is a prime or not? if yes then how?
(no calculator please)

Comment: Note that $111111111=37\times 3003003$, not $37\times 1001001$.

Comment: To finish the calculation, you have to show that $333667$ is prime which is not easy without a calculator. I do not think there is much merit to do it since the principal method (for example trial division) is clear. Maybe off-topic : Someone used the sundays of three years to factor $2^{67}-1$.

Comment: It is indeed a prime by the way, but as Peter says that can be time consuming to prove by hand. [Wiki on Primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

Comment: The deterministic Rabin-Miller test need only be performed with a=2 and 3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants

Comment: @YvesDaoust Probably the best here, but by hand this is still cumbersome.

Comment: @Peter: with primes there is no free lunch...